# Get all has_many instances for each collection item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the models of:

`Task` which `has_many :comments` and `has_many :checklists`

`Comment` which `has_many :activities`

`Checklist` which `has_many :activities`

-> (polymorphic association).

I want to get every `Activity` there is in a `Task`, for example, if I do something like:

```
Task.first.checklists.first.activities
```

it returns result, so does:

```
Task.first.comments.first.activities`
```

but I can not manage to write proper syntax that gets me every activity there is in a Task, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `has_many` `through:` associations:

```
class Task 
  has_many :comments
  has_many :checklists

  has_many :comment_activities, through: :comments, source: :activities
  has_many :checklist_activities, through: :checklists, source: :activities
end
```

and use them as follows:

```
Task.first.checklist_activities
Task.first.comment_activities
```

Comment: `has_many :activities, through: :comments`. You have to use the `source:` option if you want to alias it.